# Find the percentage for both cash and credit

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, percentage

So, I have a column 'Type' that has cash and credit transactions. I want to find the percentage for both as results. Can anybody help me accomplish this?

```
SELECT COUNT(Type),
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Cash' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) * 100 AS PercentageCashTransaction,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Credit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) * 100 AS PercentageCreditTransaction
FROM vending_machine_sales
GROUP BY type;
```

Actual results:

| TYPE | %Cash | %Credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2148 | 0 | 100 |
| 4297 | 100 | 0 |

Desired results:

| %Cash | %Credit |
| --- | --- |
| 67% | 33% |

Comment: An INT divided by an INT will return an INT.   Try  ...  Type = 'Cash' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 ...

Comment: I am not sure why you are doing a GROUP BY, but remove it.  And remove the COUNT(type) and then make the change that John suggested and you will get your desired result.

Comment: I can't see the rest of your comment john.

Comment: You can see all he posted, that's all you need to get your query working

Comment: Just to clarify.  In your CASE change 1 to 1.0 and 0 to 0.0

Comment: Just an side.  If you want to message an individual, prefix the desired name with an @ symbol

Comment: @JohnCappelletti quick question, how would you turn this into a whole percentage? I used ceiling and floor to round the decimal points. is there an easier way to do this ?

Comment: You need to ask a new question (or rather google the answer because its been asked many times before) because you need to explain whether you want to round it, in which case which form of rounding do you want to use, or truncate it.

Comment: @NickolasJaramillo  Many, many options.  This really belongs in the presentation layer.   That said, take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/DeuKtJWv